# Watch online videos locally on PC

Tags: video-player

I have seen that you can use VLC player to play online videos locally on your PC.

The problem with that, is that it is a function of VLC, so it is player dependent, and it doesn't work on every website.

So my question is if there is a program or a command-line utility (like livestreamer but for videos) for Ubuntu that works on every website and on every player (VLC or mpv etc.). I know that it is probably a longshot but I would like to know.

Answer (score -2):

Get kodi then install the add-ons Israel live, genesis Lazarus,  ccloud, and velocity. You have all the tv and movies you can imagine no websites no messy cache etc.

Comment: 1. Please [edit] to include instructions on how to install all this. 2. Does this actually answer the question? The question is about online videos, not TV channels or movies.